# Laptop Display doesn't turn on after waking up from suspend2ram on linux

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, suspend, xiaomi

My laptop screen and keyboard backlight doesn't work after waking up from sleep but the laptop wakes up (sometimes rarely it works as I open the lid)

, like if I suspend it while watching a video, after waking up pressing the spacebar plays the audio but the screen is blank and I can't increase it's brightness

I've tried multiple distros, kernels (lts,zen) currently using Endeavouros but nothing works

Other users also facing same issue and its been unsolved for nearly a year

Any help is appreciated.

````
❯ inxi -Fxz

System:
  Kernel: 6.4.12-arch1-1 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.1
    Desktop: Hyprland Distro: EndeavourOS base: Arch Linux
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: TIMI product: Xiaomi NoteBook Pro v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: TIMI model: TM2105 v: V1.0 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: TIMI
    v: RMAAD4B0P0A0A date: 05/16/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 55.4 Wh (98.8%) condition: 56.1/56.0 Wh (100.2%)
    volts: 17.5 min: N/A model: SCUD R14B06W status: not charging
CPU:
  Info: 8-core (4-mt/4-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i5-12450H bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP arch: Alder Lake rev: 3 cache: L1: 704 KiB L2: 7 MiB
    L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1656 high: 2500 min/max: 400/4400:3300 cores: 1: 1526
    2: 2500 3: 1431 4: 969 5: 616 6: 2500 7: 869 8: 523 9: 1441 10: 2500
    11: 2500 12: 2500 bogomips: 59916
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P GT1 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Xiaomi driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-12.2 bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: Sunplus Innovation XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam driver: uvcvideo
    type: USB bus-ID: 3-4:2
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.0
    compositor: Hyprland driver: X: loaded: intel unloaded: modesetting
    dri: i965 gpu: i915 resolution: 1280x800~120Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.1.6-arch1.4 renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL
    GT2) direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio vendor: Xiaomi
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Device-2: Generic Quarks DSP driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
    type: USB bus-ID: 3-1:5
  API: ALSA v: k6.4.12-arch1-1 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: sndiod v: N/A status: off
  Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.78 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.3
  IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: virbr0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB
    bus-ID: 3-10:4
  Report: btmgmt ID: hci0 rfk-id: 3 state: down bt-service: disabled
    rfk-block: hardware: no software: no address: N/A
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 139.34 GiB (29.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: KIOXIA model: N/A size: 476.94 GiB temp: 31.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 459.08 GiB used: 139.04 GiB (30.3%) fs: btrfs
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /home size: 459.08 GiB used: 139.04 GiB (30.3%) fs: btrfs
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-3: /var/log size: 459.08 GiB used: 139.04 GiB (30.3%) fs: btrfs
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 16.87 GiB used: 60.7 MiB (0.4%)
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
Sensors:
  Src: /sys System Temperatures: cpu: 36.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
  Power: 12v: N/A 5v: 5 3.3v: N/A vbat: N/A
Info:
  Processes: 314 Uptime: 8h 57m Memory: total: 16 GiB note: est.
  available: 15.34 GiB used: 5.7 GiB (37.2%) Init: systemd Compilers:
  gcc: 13.2.1 clang: 16.0.6 Packages: 1868 Shell: Zsh v: 5.9 inxi: 3.3.29 ```
````